# How to find element that are not present in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of hundreds codes like :

> '123XXX465', '321YYY654',..., '789ZZZ321'

And a table A with a column Code I want to find easily all codes that are not in the table A and I have no clues on how to do this.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Make a table B with column list_code and import your list, then:

```
SELECT
B.list_code,
A.Code
FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON B.list_code=A.Code
WHERE A.Code IS NULL;
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the clue !